# Python not writing to MySQL (Type Error: format requires a mapping)

Tags: python, mysql, mapping

I am using a python programme to log data to a MySQL database.  The database connection is made but I am getting the following error `Type Error: format requires a mapping` when the log is written.

The code of interest is as follows:

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE pidRun
(
pidKey INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
pidSetPoint INT,
pidMeasure FLOAT,
pidError FLOAT,
integrator FLOAT,
derivator FLOAT
);
```

Python Code:

```
# Insert a new line to table pidRun
add_pidRun = ("INSERT INTO pidRun "
              "(pidSetPoint, pidMeasure, pidError, integrator, derivator)"
              "VALUES (%(pidSetPoint)i, %(pidMeasure)f, %(pidError)f, %(integrator)f, %(derivator)f)")
```

Then the code to insert the line at the requisite point is here:

`data_pidRun = (pidControl.getPoint(), centSpeed, errSpeed, 0.0, 0.0)
        cursor.execute(add_pidRun, data_pidRun)
        dBase.commit()`

pidControl.getPoint is a Integer

centSpeed is a float

errspeed is a float

Any direction is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, placeholders like `%(pidSetPoint)` require a mapping to be passed to `cursor.execute()`. Since you use a tuple, change the placeholders to `"%s"`:

```
add_pidRun = ("INSERT INTO pidRun "
              "(pidSetPoint, pidMeasure, pidError, integrator, derivator)"
              "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s")
data_pidRun = (pidControl.getPoint(), centSpeed, errSpeed, 0.0, 0.0)
cursor.execute(add_pidRun, data_pidRun)
```

You don't need to specify the type of a value.

Comment: Perfect.  I need to ascertain why I should use a tuple over a list though!